# HTML Background not showing

Tags: html

I'm practicing this simple code and when I try to put a `background` on my `P` behind them using the `(div) element` its not showing why is that?
What I want is for the `div { background-color: purple; }`
covers all my `(p) section.'

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Boxes</title>
<h1 align="center">My Boxes</h1>


<style>

div {
    background-color: purple;

}


p { width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float:left;
}
h1 {margin-bottom: 80px;
}

* {box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;}

#box1   {background-color: yellow;




}
#box2   {background-color: red;


}
#box3   {background-color: blue;
    clear:left; 

}
#box4   {background-color: green;}



</style>
</head> 

<body>
<div>

<p id="box1"> </p>
<p id="box2"> </p>
<p id="box3"> </p>
<p id="box4"> </p>  

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is because you have added `float: left` to your `p` which makes the elements float inside div and that is why div has not taken any height. You do not need to add this style to make elements stick to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use overflow: auto to DIV as you have used float to the p should clear the float to recognized height of the parent.

```css
div {
    background-color: purple;
    overflow:auto;

}


p { width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float:left;
}
h1 {margin-bottom: 80px;
}

* {box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;}

#box1   {background-color: yellow;




}
#box2   {background-color: red;


}
#box3   {background-color: blue;
    clear:left; 

}
#box4   {background-color: green;}
```

```html
<div>

<p id="box1"> </p>
<p id="box2"> </p>
<p id="box3"> </p>
<p id="box4"> </p>  

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're markup is using the `<p>` tag not the `<div>` tag.

```
#box1 p {background-color: yellow; }
#box2 p {background-color: red; }
#box3 p {background-color: blue; clear:left;}
#box4 p {background-color: green; }
```

Also this belongs inside the `<body>`:

```
<h1>My Boxes</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just You Put  height:100vh; width:100%; in Div tag selector class in your css

```css
div {
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  background: purple;
          
}


p { width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float:left;
}
h1 {margin-bottom: 80px;
}

* {box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;}

#box1   {background-color: yellow;




}
#box2   {background-color: red;


}
#box3   {background-color: blue;
    clear:left; 

}
#box4   {background-color: green;}
```

```html
<body>
<div>

<p id="box1"> </p>
<p id="box2"> </p>
<p id="box3"> </p>
<p id="box4"> </p>  

</div>
```